# Different formula to find $2\times 2$ Hamiltonian's eigenvalues

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, two-level-system

Consider the Hamiltonian 
$$
\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    E_1 & -A\\
   -A& E_2\\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
$$

where $A$, $E_1,E_2$ are real numbers. I have seen a different formula to calculate the eigenvalues of this matrix, here it is:

$$\lambda = \frac{E_1 +E_2}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{(E_1 - E_2)^2}{4} + A^2}.$$

To demonstrate it, I have written:

$$\begin{equation}
 H = \frac{E_1 +E_2}{2}I + \frac{E_1 - E_2}{2} \sigma_z -A\sigma_x
\end{equation}$$
where $I$ is the identity and $\sigma_x, \sigma_z$ are the Pauli matrices.

So, the part $\frac{E_1 +E_2}{2}$ comes from the eigenvalues of the identity,but how do you obtain the second part?

Comment: There is no easy way to calculate the eigenvalues of a matrix.
The straight-forward way is to solve the equation $\text{det}(\lambda I - H)=0$.
In your case, this will lead to a quadratic equation for $\lambda$ with the 2 solutions given in your question.

Comment: I think it should be $$\lambda = \frac{E_1+E_2}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{(E_1-E_2)^2}{4}+A^2}$$ The square of the difference under the root is missing.

Comment: I fixed the missing square, thank you. I know that I can solve the problem by calculating det($\lambda I - H$)=0, but I was interested in understanding this different approach with the Pauli matrices.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch What do you mean there is no easy way to calculate eigenvalues?

Comment: I mean, when $H$ is the sum of two matrices $A$ and $B$,
then the eigenvalues of $H$ are not just the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ (except for the special case when $AB=BA$).
And finding them by solving $det(\lambda I-H)=0$ may be easy for 2x2 matrices, but it becomes much harder for larger nxn matrices.

Comment: So, is the question how to get from your 3rd equation (H=...) to your 2nd equation (λ=...) without calculating the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @ThomasFritsch You mean by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvectors of the hamiltonian are null vectors $\psi$ of $H-\lambda \mathbb{I}$ for some eigenvalues $\lambda$.

So 
$$
(H-\lambda \mathbb{I})\psi =0=\left  ( \frac{E_1 +E_2-2\lambda}{2}\mathbb{I} + \frac{E_1 - E_2}{2} \sigma_z -A\sigma_x \right )\psi \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
\left  (\frac{E_1 - E_2}{2} \sigma_z -A\sigma_x \right)\psi=-\left ( \frac{E_1 +E_2-2\lambda}{2}\mathbb{I}\right)\psi  \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
\left  (\frac{E_1 - E_2}{2} \sigma_z -A\sigma_x \right)^2\psi=-\left ( \frac{E_1 +E_2-2\lambda}{2}\mathbb{I} \right ) \left (\frac{E_1 - E_2}{2} \sigma_z -A\sigma_x  \right )\psi  =\left ( \frac{E_1 +E_2-2\lambda}{2}\mathbb{I}\right)^2\psi  \qquad \Longrightarrow \\
\left
(A^2 +\left (\frac{E_1 - E_2}{2}\right )^2   \right   )\psi =\left ( \frac{E_1 +E_2-2\lambda}{2}\right )^2\psi ,
$$
since each Pauli matrix squares to the identity and the two anticommute.

You then have your  algebraic equation 
$$
\pm \sqrt{A^2 +\frac{(E_1 - E_2)^2}{4}}       = \frac{E_1 +E_2}{2} -\lambda
$$ 
without determinants, etc... Perhaps hardly worth it.